# Ruby multiple inheritance needed for rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, multiple-inheritance

First off, let me say that I know that multiple inheritance is not possible in Ruby, but when I think about it, that's the only way I can see a resolution.

I have 3 separate user classes that all share single-table inheritance. Here they are

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications
  def notify
    #code to notify user
  end
end

class Student < User
  has_many :charges
  def charge_user
    #code to charge user
  end
end

class Teacher < Student
  has_many :students
  has_many :courses
  def create_course
    #code to create course
  end
end
```

I want to be able to use each has_many method only once, and the Teacher must inherit all the Student methods

The problem if this is if I run

```
Teacher.find(1)
```

I get this error

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'Teacher'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite User.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.
```

If I change the teacher class to

```
class Teacher < User
end
```

It works, however, now the teacher doesn't have all the has_many methods and normal methods that the student has.

Comment: Hi, why doesn't  `User` class inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`?. Has your `users` table a column named `type`? This is needed for single table inheritance.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo, the ActiveRecord::Base has been in my class, updated the question. Also, yes I have the type column, and as I said, I can find the Teacher just fine if I change Teacher to inherit from User.

Comment: Use concerns or just repeat the associations. That's not too big a sin here.

Comment: @Deep That wouldn't make sense, because the type column is required for single-table inheritance

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you, concerns are exactly what I need here

Comment: As suggested by @SergioTulentsev , use concerns and move the methods there.

Comment: Also, the inheritance usage here is not theoretically pure. A teacher __isn't__ a special type of student. Must be you have some unnamed entities there (that concern)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In my case, a Teacher can also be a Student at the same time, learning from other Teachers using the same account. does that still make logical sense?

Comment: @JeffDavenport: ah, in this case, yes. :) Still, I probably wouldn't do STI here. It feels like a good case for role-based code.

Comment: Okay cool haha.

Comment: Nah, "use concerns" is hardly a proper answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The reason that I have moved to STI here is because my single User class has gotten so large it's becoming difficult to mange with all the student methods and teacher methods in the same spot, I suppose I could use modules to separate them, only thing, is with the code that we have, it makes more sense for a student to not be able to access all the teacher methods, this is the simplest way I could think to do that

Comment: @JeffDavenport: Yes, I trust you had good reasons.

Comment: concerns are a pretty minimal wrapper over modules, which more generally compensate for the single-inheritance rule. See [here](http://engineering.appfolio.com/appfolio-engineering/2013/06/17/ruby-mixins-activesupportconcern) for a tutorail on how to emulate concern functionality with a regular module.